# Filter Products by category when category page loads angular

Tags: angular

I have a angular webapp that displays all the categories from the category model. The category model is a foreign key the products model. I want to be able to filter and view all the products that has that category when I click and load that specific category view.

When I click on a category at the minute it takes me to a details page where I can see the category name, image and description. I can also see all of the products in my DB within that details view. I want to filter these so that only the products that contain that specific category in its foreign key field will be shown in the category details view rather than all of the products.

If anyone could help me out here it would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far:

department.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/api.service';
import { Category } from '../../models/Category';
import { Product } from '../../models/Product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-department',
  templateUrl: './department.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./department.component.css']
})
export class DepartmentComponent implements OnInit {

  categories: Category[] = [];

  constructor(
    private cookieService: CookieService,
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCategories()
  }

  getCategories(): void {
    const urToken = this.cookieService.get('ur-token')
    if (!urToken) {
      this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
    } else {

      this.apiService.getCategories().subscribe(
        data => {
          this.categories = data;
        },
        error => console.log(error)

      );
    }
  }

}
```

department.component.html

```
<section class="pt-5 pb-5">
  <div class="container cards cards-hover">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5  m-0 p-0" *ngFor="let category of categories">
        <app-department-item [categoryItem]="category" routerLink="details/{{ category.id }}"></app-department-item>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

department-details.component.html

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Category } from '../../models/Category';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { ApiService } from '../../api.service';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/Product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-department-details',
  templateUrl: './department-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./department-details.component.css']
})
export class DepartmentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  category!: Category;
  products: Product[] = []
  selectedProduct?: Product;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private location: Location,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCategory()
    this.getProducts()
  }

  getCategory(): void {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.apiService.getCategory(id)
      .subscribe(category => this.category = category);
  }

  getProducts(): void {
    this.apiService.getProducts().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.products = data;
        console.log('selectedProduct', this.products);
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }

  selectProduct(product: Product) {
    this.router.navigate(['main/products/details', product.product_code]);
  }


}
```

department-details.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="category">
  <div class="">
    <div class="container  ">

      <div class="row   justify-content-center header-h100  d-flex  ">
        <div class="col-md-10  shadow align-self-center card p-12 bg-light text-dark pt-4 pb-4">
          <img src="{{category.category_image}}" class="img-center img">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h1>{{category.name}}</h1><br>
            <h5>{{ category.category_description }}</h5><br>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
        <div class="container cards cards-hover">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4  m-0 p-0" *ngFor="let product of products">
              <app-product-item [productItem]="product" (click)="selectProduct(product)"></app-product-item>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to figure out which parameters you have to send to the api endpoint. You can filter the products in the frontend, but what you really want is that your api only gives the correct products. So, first step is, search your api docs how to filter the products

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about that?